# Maven cannot resolve dependency due to plus sign in version

Tags: maven, build, gradle

I have a maven dependency that has a version declaration "19.+", and maven is failing, even though the same dependency with version 20.0 exists in the .m2 directory.

I thought that this plus sign in the version was meant to say "fetch anything above this version". Is there anything I am missing?

P.S. that version declaration is declared inside one of my dependencies so I can't actually change it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This syntax is an Ivy version range, and not supported by Maven. It shouldn't be used in an artifact on the Central Repository, but a few made it in before valid versions were enforced.

See [Enforcing valid dependency versions](http://central.sonatype.org/articles/2014/Oct/28/enforcing-valid-dependency-versions/)  for more details:

> E.g. a version of 16.+ has a meaning of any version from 16 up to anything smaller than 17 . These could be e.g. 16.3. Using such a syntax breaks the dependency mechanism of all other build systems and as such has to be avoided. Members of the Android Maven community have alerted us to problems caused by the usage of this invalid syntax.
>
> ...
>
> we will be enforcing that no version of any dependency declaration in the pom uses this syntax or the 'latest' variant also possible in Ivy.

As of November 2014 ([Dependency version range enforcement live on OSSRH](http://central.sonatype.org/articles/2014/Nov/27/dependency-version-range-enforcement-live-on-ossrh/) ) this policy is in effect. You'll need to move to an upgraded version of that artifact. As [this post says](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/maven-dev/201411.mbox/%3C20141128165924.42C074343623@dd34514.kasserver.com%3E):

> In terms of changing old artifacts it has been a long standing rule for Central NOT to do
> any modifications. As such if you run into trouble with an artifact that uses the syntax I
> would urge you all to notify the offenders and ask them to fix it and release a new version.